# why does .str method change the shape of a pandas' series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## the type of the data

```
    In [1]: print(type(ebola_melt))
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

## the column of interest is created such this

```
    In [2]: ebola_melt['str_split'] = ebola_melt['type_country']
    .str.split('_')
    In [3]: print(type(ebola_melt['str_split']))
    <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

## .get(0) with .str method applied

```
    In [4]: ebola_melt['str_split'].str.get(0)
    Out[4]: 
    0        Cases
    1        Cases
    2        Cases
    3        Cases
    4        Cases
        ...
```

## .get(0) without .str method applied

```
    In [5]: ebola_melt['str_split'].get(0)
    Out[5]: ['Cases', 'Guinea']
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it is about the differences in get; `str.get`  is a vectorized way of getting an element from *each row* while `Series.get`  gets the index for a *particular row*.

Comment: i was expecting the result of str.get be the same as the result of Series.get. My question is why str.get method vectorize the Series, is there any insight i can get? thanks for the quick response btw

Answer (score 0):

pandas.Series.str.get extracts elements from lists in the Series/Index.

pandas.Series.get gets items from object for a given index value

Please refer documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html
and
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.get.html

so,

```
    ebola_melt['str_split']  #contains  ['Cases', 'Guinea']
    ebola_melt['str_split'].str.get(0) #returns the values present in the zeorth index of all rows which is Cases
    ebola_melt['str_split'].get(0) #returns the row present in the zeorth index 
    ebola_melt['str_split'].get #returns the all the rows
```